# How to efficiently apply LinearModelFit for each column in a matrix

Tags: fitting

I have a source vector and a matrix of targets that I want to fit a linear model for. What is a more "Mathematica" way of doing this?. Here is my code to do it for the first column in target matrix:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[{vnSource, mnTarget[[All, 1]]}\[Transpose], x, x};
lm["BestFitParameters"]
```

What I need are two vectors - one for each of the two best fit parameters for each column in the mnTarget matrix.

===== Here is a working example:

```
iHistoryLength  = 150;
iTargetVectors = 10;
vnSource = 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1., 0.1], iHistoryLength];
mnTarget = 
  RandomVariate[
   NormalDistribution[1., 0.1], {iHistoryLength, iTargetVectors}];

lm = LinearModelFit[{vnSource, mnTarget[[All, 1]]}\[Transpose], x, 
   x];
lm["BestFitParameters"]
```

The last line produces two parameters for the first column of mnTarget.
What I need are two vectors: one for the first parameter for all columns in mnTarget and one for the second. Thank you!

Hope this makes sense. I feel like Table[lm["BestFitParameters"], .... should do it, but am not sure how to correctly finish this statement.

Thank you for your help!

======= edit 2:

this is brilliant, thank you
both solutions work:

by Syed:

```
lm = LinearModelFit[{vnSource, mnTarget[[All, #]]}\[Transpose], x, x][
   "BestFitParameters"] & /@ Range[iTargetVectors]
```

by Ulrich:

```
lm = Map[LinearModelFit[{vnSource, #}\[Transpose], x, x][
   "BestFitParameters"] &, mnTarget\[Transpose]]
```

How can I now split the resulting matrix into two columns?

Comment: Please check the `ArrayReduce` function and present a minimal example for a focused Q&A. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I just added an example.

Comment: `lm = LinearModelFit[{vnSource, mnTarget[[All, #]]}\[Transpose], x, x][
    "BestFitParameters"] & /@ Range[iTargetVectors]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
Map[{#, LinearModelFit[{vnSource, #}\[Transpose], x, x]["BestFitParameters"]} & , Transpose[mnTarget]]
```

Minimal working example would be helpful!

**addendum**

```
Map[ LinearModelFit[{vnSource, #}\[Transpose], x, x]["BestFitParameters"] & , Transpose[mnTarget]] //Transpose
(*{{1.00806, 1.07279, 1.10537, 0.900509, 1.02147, 0.999576, 0.926018,0.864081, 0.873018, 1.06353},
{-0.00964781, -0.0754324, -0.0931327,0.102227, -0.0354254, 0.00878964,0.0805215, 0.124233, 0.125088, -0.0753679}}*)
```

gives the two parametervectors of BestFitParameters!

Comment: Thank you. I just added an example.

Comment: It work if I transpose mnTarget!  Thank you. All I need now is to split the resulting matrix into two vectors....  `Map[LinearModelFit[{vnSource, #}\[Transpose], x, x][
   "BestFitParameters"] &, mnTarget\[Transpose]]`

Comment: What are the two(!) bestfit vectors you want to save?

Comment: @IgorBinder See my modified answer !